# iptables drop length and TTL condition doesn't work

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

With `iptables` utility on Linux host need to create mini firewall. I need to drop all incoming connections with package length greater than 722 AND TTL greater than 22. Need exactly AND. Drop only if both conditions are TRUE.

```
sudo iptables -N LOGDROP
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -m ttl --ttl-gt 22 -j LOGDROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m ttl --ttl-gt 22 -j LOGDROP
sudo iptables -A LOGDROP -m length --length 722:65535 -j DROP
```

IP-adress of host is `10.6.7.9` with firewall.

I did 4 test from this host, trying to ping another host:

```
ping -s 10000 -t 250 10.6.7.10 //fail (TTL AND LENGHT are wrong)
ping -s 100 -t 200 10.6.7.10 //success (TTL is wrong)
ping -s 10 -t 10 10.6.7.10 //success (Both are right)
ping -s 10000 -t 10 10.6.7.10 // fail, BUT SHOULD BE TRUE.
```

Why last ping doesn't work ,and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If the two conditions must be true at the same time, you should construct the conditions like:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -m ttl --ttl-gt 22 -m length --length 722:65535 -j DROP

sudo iptables -A INPUT -m ttl --ttl-gt 22 -m length --length 722:65535 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

A good possibility is that the ping reply from the remote host has a larger TTL, as the `-t` option only sets the outgoing packet's TTL.    A common default TTL these days is 64.  (I believe the recommendation is twice the width of the internet.)

Another possibility would be that, since the 10000 byte ping had to be fragmented, the remote host refused to reply to it.  Try sending an 800 byte ping.

Also, if you do `sudo iptables -L -v` it will tell you how many times the rule has hit.  This can be useful for debugging.

Another debugging option is to do a rule like:

```
sudo iptables -A LOGDROP -m length --length 722:65535 -j LOG
```

Before the DROP rule.  This will log the packet to the kernel log (read with `dmesg`) before dropping it.  You can then work out what was dropped.